# How do I prevent anonymous requests to a REST API / NGINX server while allowing authenticated requests to endpoints?

Tags: rest, http, security, nginx, reverse-proxy

## Initial disclosure:

I’m new to nginx and reverse proxy configuration in general.

## Background

I have a Swagger-derived, FOSS, https-accessible REST API [written by another party] running on a certain port of an EC2 CentOS 7 instance behind an nginx 1.16.1 reverse proxy (to path `https://foo_domain/bar_api/`); for my purposes,  this API needs to be reachable from a broad variety of services not all of which publish their IP ranges, i.e., the API must be exposed to traffic from any IP.

Access to the API’s data endpoints (e.g., `https://foo_domain/bar_api/resource_id`) is controlled by a login function located at
`https://foo_domain/bar_api/foobar/login`
supported by token auth, which is working fine.

## Problem

However, the problem is that an anonymous user is able to GET

`https://foo_domain/bar_api`

without logging in, which results in potentially sensitive data about the API server configuration being returned, such as the API’s true port, server version, some of the available endpoints and parameters, etc.  This is not acceptable for the purpose, from a security standpoint.

## Question

How do I prevent anonymous GET requests to the /bar_api/ endpoint, while allowing login and authenticated data requests to endpoints *beyond* /bar_api/ to proceed unhindered? Or, otherwise, how do I prevent any data from being *returned* upon such requests?